# How to add extra data to a wx.TextCtrl?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

How can I add extra data to wx.TextCtrl widgets?

At the moment I'm using the GetToolTipString() method to add the extra data but this is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about adding data to it like you can with a [ComboBox or ListBox](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/16/wxpython-storing-object-in-combobox-or-listbox-widgets/), well, you can't. That's not a part of the TextCtrl. However, you could probably subclass wx.TextCtrl and add that functionality or just create some kind of data structure that is keyed on the data you add to the control.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, was hoping it would have something similar to a Combobox or ListBox

Comment: so I just need to make a subclass, with lets say methods called SetExtraData() and GetExtraData(), for the wx.TextCtrl class?

Comment: please have a look at this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168256/creating-subclass-for-wx-textctrl

Answer (score 0):

ummmm  `my_text_control.SetValue("some value to set")`  ??

If you clarify your question ill clarify my answer